# Unable to connect to mysql in docker container from another docker container

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I have two docker containers: mysql and spring boot service.
Service container is not connecting to mysql container(failing on the deploy) with following exception:
`CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`
So far I have tried using docker --link, docker networks, running everything using/without docker compose. 
I am able to connect to DB container outside of docker.

Connection string: `jdbc:mysql://db:3306/somedb`

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "80:8060"
    links:
    - db
    depends_on:
    - db

  db:
    image: "mysql:latest"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=somedb
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
    - /Users/someuser/someproject/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: You may also want to look at using user-defined networks instead https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/. Links have been deprecated for awhile. https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: Thanks, @Schmango, as I mentioned in post, I've tried to create a network and run containers in it, no success though.

Comment: Ah right sorry about that. Just tested this dockerfile with different images and the link is working properly for me. Any chance you could push your app container image to Dockerhub so we can test your exact setup?

Comment: It's under NDA, but huge thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Can you try removing the `links`? Is not necessary as docker-compose will already create a docker network. Also check that the DB is working, try accessing it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my service dockerfile I say:

```
ADD target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app-service.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app-service.jar'
```

But I forgot to rebuild jar after making changes in service config files
TL;DR I'm retarded

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier and i tried with by changing the mysql image version. Here is my compose yaml file where i am able to connect it with.

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  spring-boot-container:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    links: 
      - mysql-standalone

  mysql-standalone:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: springsecurity
      MYSQL_USER: sa
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried changing image version and it didn't work for me, same error.